# Is pagination(scrolling months in the calendar horizontally using arrows) possible in time square calendar in android?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-time-square

This is what we want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkEHC.jpg)

This is what we are getting now using time square:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOICs.png)

we wish to select multiple dates(random not in range) at the same time which apparently caldroid does not support.So is there anything else i can use besides using caldroid.

Thanks

Comment: There are many site for this.i have posted some reference of site.

Comment: @VishalThakkar  actually we wish to select multiple dates(random not in range) at the same time which apparently caldroid does not support.Could you please suggest something based on this requirement.      Thanks

Comment: you did not write this in your question.

Comment: @VishalThakkar  i forgot to mention that but is there still any way you can help.

Comment: i have updated answer try that link it help you.